# Javascript For Loop Refactor Due to ESLint Rules and Best Practices

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, eslint

I need assistance refactoring my code to ES6 best practices and passing the below ESLinting rules. Below is my entire method. The for loop here is the issue.

```
formatNumber(val) {
  if (!isFinite(val)) {
    return val;
  }
  const valFloat = val.toString();
  const decPos = valFloat.indexOf('.');
  const intPart = (decPos === -1) ? valFloat : valFloat.substr(0, decPos);
  const formattedNum = [];
  // this needs refactoring
  for (const ii in intPart) {
    if (ii % 3 === 0 && ii !== 0) {
      formattedNum.push();
    }
    formattedNum.push(intPart[intPart.length - 1 - ii]);
  }
  formattedNum.reverse();

  return (decPos === -1) ? formattedNum.join('') : formattedNum.join('') + valFloat.slice(decPos, valFloat.length);
}
```

```
ESLint: The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.(guard-for-in)
ESLint: for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array.(no-restricted-syntax)
```

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in? The ESlint rule pages all have examples of passing code.

Comment: Try replacing `for...in` with `for...of`, e.g. `for (const ii of intPart)`

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not particularly good fun mentally parsing code: it would be helpful if you could say what your code is doing, rather than leaving it to us to parse, especially when it's doing something as odd as looping through the keys in an array, doing a calculation on the key, then using the inverse value from the array. Most unconventional!

The problem is with a `for..in` loop, as explained in the [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in). This ESLint rule requires that, if you use a `for..in` loop, you run `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` on each key, to make sure it's part of the object you want, rather than coming from some other code that's added a property to `Object.prototype` (or, in this case, also `String.prototype`). This is sensible defensive coding.

So you *could* do this:

```
for (const ii in intPart) {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(intPart, ii)) {
    continue;
  }
...
```

But that to me is not a nice solution, and it's actually possible to refactor your code in a nicer, more easy to follow way that also deals with this problem:

```
const formattedNum = intPart
  .split('') // split the string into an array of digits
  .reduceRight((acc, val, idx) => { // loop through the array with a reducer function, starting at the right
    acc.unshift(val); // add the digit to the beginning of the output array

    if (
      idx && // if it's not the first item in the array (where idx === 0)
      ((intPart.length - idx) % 3 === 0) // and it is a multiple of three from the end of the array
    ) {
      acc.unshift(','); // add a comma to the beginning of the array
    }

    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current proposed program only "formats" a number based on (presumably) your locale. My advise is not to fix a program that is on the 
 wrong path entirely. Consider [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and the need for your `formatNumber` function disappears -

```js
num.toLocaleString([locales [, options]])
```

Using `locales` parameter -

```js
var number = 123456.789;

// German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
// → 123.456,789

// Arabic in most Arabic speaking countries uses Eastern Arabic digits
console.log(number.toLocaleString('ar-EG'));
// → ١٢٣٤٥٦٫٧٨٩

// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
// → 1,23,456.789

// the nu extension key requests a numbering system, e.g. Chinese decimal
console.log(number.toLocaleString('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec'));
// → 一二三,四五六.七八九

// when requesting a language that may not be supported, such as
// Balinese, include a fallback language, in this case Indonesian
console.log(number.toLocaleString(['ban', 'id']));
// → 123.456,789
```

Using `options` parameter -

```js
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79 €

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(number.toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }))
// → ￥123,457

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }));
// → 1,23,000

// Use the host default language with options for number formatting
var num = 30000.65;
console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
// → "30,000.65" where English is the default language, or
// → "30.000,65" where German is the default language, or
// → "30 000,65" where French is the default language
```